# Measurability of a point process or random measure at a measurable subset

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

1. Suppose     $\xi$ is a point process
   on $(S, B(S))$, where $S$ be locally
   compact second countable Hausdorff
   space equipped with its Borel
   σ-algebra $B(S)$.

   I was wondering if $\xi(A), \forall
       A \in B(S)$ is measurable, i.e. an
   integer-valued random variable? So
   that, for example, it makes sense to
   talk about   $ E ( \xi(A) )$? If not, are there some cases when it is true?
2. More generally, same questions for a
   random measure instead of a point
   process?
3. If the answers to the above
   questions are yes, can we say a
   point process or random measure is a
   stochastic process with index set
   being the $\sigma$-algebra $B(S)$?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I was wondering, did you try to read a classic on Poisson point processes, such as *Poisson Processes* by J. F. C. Kingman http://www.amazon.com/Poisson-Processes-Oxford-Studies-Probability/dp/0198536933, which is very welcoming and not so long, or another reference given on the linked page?